# How to share Postgresql database with two different websites? ( ruby and Heroku )

Tags: ruby, heroku

How can we share one database with two different websites?

I made a web-application( for customer ) with Ruby On Rails using Heroku server. I need to make provider site that shares same information with the customer site. All data is stored in the Heroku server. How can I do this and is it possible to do?

Please give any thought about this!! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an article at Heroku devcenter about that topic : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku

This article seems to cover all your needs.

Comment: Thanks!! I did it. Thanks a lot. Would you give me any advice how to read-write the data from Heroku server ( identical server and data in it )?

Comment: You are welcome :) what kind of data are you talking about : files ?